# Legend toggling for d3.js pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a d3.js application.

In this example I am trying to toggle the slices when the user clicks on the legend components. It will initially take the complete data as its source, but if there is a previous manipulated data source will use that as a base. I've tried to hook into the toggling functionality as the legend is manipulated. I would prefer to separate the functionality - but wasn't sure how else to know if the slice is to be active or not.

Its not working as expected though, especially when trying to handle multiple active/non active slices.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3282/

```
 onLegendClick: function(dt, i){
                    //_toggle rectangle in legend

var completeData = jQuery.extend(true, [], methods.currentDataSet);




                    newDataSet = completeData;                        
                    if(methods.manipulatedData){
                        newDataSet = methods.manipulatedData;
                    }


                    d3.selectAll('rect')
                    .data([dt], function(d) { 
                        return d.data.label;
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity", function(d, j) {
                        var isActive = Math.abs(1-d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity"));
                        if(isActive){
                            newDataSet[j].total = completeData[j].total;                                
                        }else{
                            newDataSet[j].total = 0;                            
                        }

                        return isActive;
                    });                            

                    //animate slices
                    methods.animateSlices(newDataSet);

                    //stash manipulated data
                    methods.manipulatedData = newDataSet;

                }
```

Comment: I need to work out a way of hiding the labels, when the slices are set to 0 - so no overlapping occurs.

Comment: Here is a version where the labels/pointers get hidden on 0 value slices. http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3321/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3324/ latest version 23/10/2014

Comment: Very latest - http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3328/ - slices are now correctly tweened out and into existence - although need support creating the reset function to stop the pie chart becoming null

Comment: Tweening needs improvement too - as the slices pop into existence then re-tween smootlhy

Answer (score 0):

Here is the onLegendClick function.

I am toggling the opacity of the inner fill on the rectangle when the user clicks.

I've tried to modify the value of the data accordingly - although it is not handling multiple toggles.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3324/
Ideally if the user tries to deactivate all slices, I would want it to reset the chart and restore all the slices in the process. Would be keen to streamline the code and maybe separate the logic and presentation layer for the styling of the rectangles in the legend.

line 234

```
 onLegendClick: function(dt, i){
                    //_toggle rectangle in legend

                    var completeData = jQuery.extend(true, [], methods.currentDataSet);

                    newDataSet = completeData;                        
                    if(methods.manipulatedData){
                        newDataSet = methods.manipulatedData;
                    }


                    d3.selectAll('rect')
                    .data([dt], function(d) { 
                        return d.data.label;
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity", function(d, j) {
                        var isActive = Math.abs(1-d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity"));
                        if(isActive){
                            newDataSet[j].total = completeData[j].total;                                
                        }else{
                            newDataSet[j].total = 0;                            
                        }

                        return isActive;
                    });                            



                    //animate slices
                    methods.animateSlices(newDataSet);

                    //stash manipulated data
                    methods.manipulatedData = newDataSet;

                }
```